# AppleScript Syntax error while working around UI elements (Summary Service)

Tags: objective-c, service, syntax, applescript, summarization

I'm trying to get/set value from Summary Service application using this code

```
tell application "SummaryService"
    activate
    delay 0.1
    get value of text area 1 of scroll area 1 of window "Summary" 
end tell
```

And whatever I do (get or set) I get this error
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lrirg.png)

(!) Generally, I'd like to find a way of launching Summary App with text as an argument (I want to add this possibility into my obj-c app). I've googled for some time and what I get is [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/82287/how-to-use-mac-os-xs-summary-service-on-the-command-line). Nevertheless it makes all the work behind scenes, giving to user only result of text transformation and makes to do some amount of unnecessary work, while I just want to launch default app.
Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally I don't solve my question in the way I previously want, but I found that there're many opensource summerize libs on github, so I use [one](https://github.com/fdzsergio/Reductio)

Just one moment since I want to use code written in Swift in my Objective-C project is to add

```
#import <Reductio/Reductio-Swift.h>
```

To controller where I want to implement desired functionality and call

```
[Reductio summarizeWithText:textToChange compression:compressionValue completion:^(NSArray<NSString *> * _Nonnull result) {}];
```

To get result.

PS: I still interested how to open SummaryService programmatically with text I choose.

PS 2: Suddenly I found such function as NSPerformService, which do exactly what I want. So I implement all the needed functionality in this way:

```
NSString *stringToSetInPb = @"sample text";
NSPasteboard *pb = [NSPasteboard pasteboardWithUniqueName];
[pb declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSStringPboardType] owner:nil];
[pb setString:stringToSetInPb forType:NSStringPboardType];
NSPerformService(@"Summarize", pb);
```

So question officially can be solved!

Answer (score 0):

System Events can get windows, scroll areas and text areas, SummaryService can't.

```
tell application "SummaryService" to activate
delay 0.1
tell application "System Events"
    tell application process "SummaryService"
        get value of text area 1 of scroll area 1 of window "Summary"
    end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you, it's a right way to get text, but I can't set it. What the problem can be? I try to write   
set value of text area 1 of scroll area 1 of window 1 to "test text"
But no success.

Comment: The algorithm of calling Summarize with text is to select text and via right mouse click call this service, so maybe there is possibility to apply calling of service to text or pass the arguments while calling? In my given links there is example with stdin/out, but as I understand this is only for CLI, maybe there can be smth for GUI?

Comment: Do you want AppleScript or is Objective-C in a Cocoa app ok?

Comment: It doesn't matter, I want to implement desired functionality, so I can insert both AppleScript and Objective-C code in Cocoa app